# How can I update my nodeJS to the latest version?

Tags: apt, nodejs

I have installed nodeJS on Ubuntu with following code

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Since I am a new user for ubuntu I also ran this code too

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Now when I type

```
 nodejs --version
```

It shows

```
v0.6.19
```

I checked and saw latest nodeJS version is `0.10.26`

How can I update my version of nodeJS to `0.10.26`?

I tried with

```
 sudo apt-get install <packagename>
 sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade <packagename>
```

but no luck.

Comment: It's better to use nvm to install nodejs. It stands for "Node Version Manager". You can very easily install multiple versions of nodejs, switch between them and set a default.

Answer (score 1848, accepted):

Use [n module from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) in order to upgrade node

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

To upgrade to latest version (and not current stable) version, you can use

```
sudo n latest
```

- Fix PATH:

  ```
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall nodejs-legacy     # fix /usr/bin/node
  ```
- To undo:

  ```
    sudo n rm 6.0.0     # replace number with version of Node that was installed
    sudo npm uninstall -g n
  ```

You may need to restart your terminal to see the updated node version.

Found in [David Walsh blog](http://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs)

Comment: I would advise strongly against doing this on a production instance. It can seriously mess stuff up with your global npm packages and your ability to install new ones.

Comment: I get an error:
/usr/bin/n: line 299: curl: command not found

  Error: invalid version 0.12.6

Comment: I second @Loourr this seems to be too hacky: `npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.` and what is this mysterious n package? :)

Comment: I tried this... now when I run `node` I get this error `bash: /usr/bin/node: No such file or directory` what should I do ?

Comment: @Fourat just use the absolute path - for example - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/n/bin/n stable

Comment: Everything worked perfectly while installing, but when I checked version `sudo nodejs -v` it gave me same version as was before.

Comment: @eballeste `sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/<VERSION>/bin/node /usr/bin/node` so every time you change the node version you have to create a soft link too?

Comment: if npm is misbehaving you can do:
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/7.0.0/bin/npm /usr/local/bin/npm

Comment: but still nodejs  --version sow 0.10.25

Comment: [David Walsh says use NVM instead](https://davidwalsh.name/nvm)

Comment: After switching Node.js versions using n, npm may not work properly. This should fix it (thanks @mikemoser!):

`$ curl -0 -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh`

or 

`$ sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/7.0.0/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm`

Comment: This works perfectly, but there's no need to create the softlink. After running: "sudo n stable" node version is already updated

Comment: One correction. Use the -H option in sudo otherwise it tries to use locations belonging to the current user during the install process, rather than root.

Comment: `sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/<VERSION>/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs` caused massive problems for me. Can you explain a little further into what this line is doing and how to use it correctly. This answer as is, is unclear.

Comment: i have no idea why that line was added to my answer, my original answer was what worked for me and has been edited since, several times

Comment: I removed the extra line which is not in fact needed. Hopefully it's not edited back in.

Comment: Not working: `sudo: n: command not found`

Comment: Not working - after following the steps, `node -v` still gave me the 6 version, not 10.

Comment: This method of upgrading node is now unstable and should not be used.  https://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs

Comment: This assumes the user has npm. Raspberry pi (at least the 2017-11-29 release, which isn't that old) comes with an old version of node, but not npm. The other answer that uses curl is far more portable because it is compatible with far more environments.

Comment: sudo: n: command not found

Comment: Works like a charm on Windows Linux Subsystem

Comment: `npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.` I don't know what I am doing...

Comment: Thanks! This works also great to install the LTS version: `sudo n lts`

Comment: You don't have to reboot, just log out an log in again, see: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/55862776/8398149](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55862776/8398149)

Comment: What an obnoxious command name. As if I'm going to be constantly managing my node versions.

Comment: You need to restart the terminal in order to changes apply, worth it to clarify

Comment: Working solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195952/updating-nodejs-on-ubuntu-16-04/46762957/#answer-46762957

Comment: @Loourr can you elaborate on why? So you don't recommend using `n`?

Comment: Can also use hash -d node to refresh the cache and point to the updated version of node. Much cleaner. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036278/npm-is-incorrect-version-on-latest-ubuntu-18-04-installation

Comment: https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92

Comment: Seeing all these solutions for different ways one should and should not update, pitfalls and different comments how it went wrong and messed up... shesh. Makes me afraid of even touching my npm installation. What happened to "Do one thing, and do it good"? That only applies to programmers using the tools, but not the toolmakers?

Comment: This answer should be flagged. Do not run on production server, it will mess up your node.

Comment: `npm i node` Let each package specify it's own version. Stop worrying about what version of node is installed in your system.

Comment: This works! However, not sure why apt install did not install latest in first place.

Comment: `sudo n lts` is what I needed.

Comment: thank you. saw many comment about didn't work and think the "don't forget to restart after update" need to be bold,

Comment: Dose not work, I get `npm does not support Node.js v10.19.0`

Comment: Until `sudo n latest` all worked fine. After restarting the terminal running `node - v` I get the latest. But running `nodejs --version` still gets the older one. 
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall nodejs-legacy` gives an error `E: Package 'nodejs-legacy' has no installation candidate` and
`sudo n rm <my-old-version>` says that the version is `not in downloads cache`
So how can I delete the old version? I suppose that originally I installed node with `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

Comment: For anyone who is having issues installing, I have a guide for installing `n` here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1403000/808646

Comment: $ sudo npm install -g n                                                                                                                                                                    
ERROR: npm v9.8.0 is known not to run on Node.js v10.19.0. ...

Comment: works still fine with v21.1.0. I think the path fix is not needed here

Answer (score 659):

NodeSource provides binary distributions of Node.js; complete installation instructions can be found [here](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#installation-instructions). The instructions have been copied below for your reference. Instructions are the same for updating to the latest version.

Run once:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg
sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg
```

Run whenever you want to change the major version of Node.js:

```
NODE_MAJOR=20
echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_MAJOR.x nodistro main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs -y
```

---

**Prior to August 2023:** Previously versions of this answer involved the use of a series of `setup_XX.x` scripts that you'd run to install/update Node.js:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_current.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

But as [@eis](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version/548776?noredirect=1#comment2612782_548776) pointed out, these scripts are no longer supported. To see the previous answers, please look at the [edit history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/548776/revisions) for this answer.

Comment: For me `node --version` still said "0.12.0". I had to `rm /usr/local/bin/node`, then I was able to use the newly installed version of nodejs.

Comment: Following above I ended up with no node installed any more and none installing no matter what I tried :-(

Comment: This is *installation* instructions not *upgrade* instructions. Installation implies that it's never been installed before. If you already have a version installed as the question implies, then what happens if you install a different version? Do you get version conflicts? Does the installation delete the old one?

Comment: For all confused idiots like me, it seems that running the installation will effectively replace what ever you had before. So I think you can perform either an upgrade or a downgrade with this process. I upgraded from v8 to v10 and I spotted this message in the install logs: `Unpacking nodejs (10.15.0-1nodesource1) over (8.12.0-1nodesource1) ...`, running `node -v` after the installation happily displays `v10.15.0` which is what I want.

Comment: `curl {anything} | sudo bash -` is a terrible security practice

Comment: @krubo I agree. The user should examine the script before running it. However, it _is_ from a reputable source (`nodesource.com`) and the connection is secured by HTTPS, so there is an adequate amount of trust you can place in those scripts. But yes, in general, check the scripts before you pipe it to `sudo bash`

Comment: @dayuloli — I'm pretty certain close to 0% of everyone have enough free time *and* Bash skills to read these 300 lines scripts. In practice almost everyone just looks at the domain name (like you wrote), the number of upvotes this answer has gotten, and hopes for the best. It'd be nice if instead there was a way to juts add an Apt source manually

Comment: I mean sth like:  `Append to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list  these lines:
deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x xenial main  \n
deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x xenial main`  — thanks anyway for posting the answer :- )

Comment: @KajMagnus that is a valid concern and a good suggestion. Feel free to edit the answer or create a new answer, I think it will be a good addition to the existing answers.

Comment: @dayuloli  — Good idea, now I edited the question (the edits are waiting for approval).

Comment: this one got working for me windows wsl of ubuntu

Comment: You can run `ubuntu` as `root` so why 2 different commands where 1 `sudo` command for `both envs` would suffice.

Comment: @T.Todua NodeSource is a reputable source. If you look at the **official** documentation at [Installing Node.js via package manager | Debian and Ubuntu based Linux distributions](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions), you'll see that it reads `Node.js binary distributions are available from NodeSource.`.

Comment: @dayuloli my bad if so. sorry (i've deleted my comment), i didn't know node had to use 3rd party commercial company to host their binaries. not ideal in my mind.

Comment: just one note (as my edit was rejected by moderator) I suggest, instead of having 10 duplicate paragraphs of 99% same code, just post one codeblock and as a title, mention that `instead of 13.x` you can use `12.x , ....etc` so, very long post will be more readable.

Comment: @T.Todua That is a valid suggestion; but doing so will mean people can't just find their target Node.js version and just copy + paste the commands. Also feel free to author a more concise solution as a new answer.

Comment: Does not work, I get `Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification.`

Comment: @Black Have you tried installing `ca-certificates`? (`sudo apt install ca-certificates`)

Comment: I am *very* much not a fan of this. For reasons I dont fully understand nodesource apts seem to completely break dependency management for the OS leading to paradoxical weirdness where things depend on nodejs but nodejs isnt installed but nodejs IS installed so you cant install it.

Comment: "https://deb.nodesource.com" says it the script is deprecated so do not use this.

Answer (score 99):

I also recommend using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) instead, and also removing the already installed version to avoid conflicts in the terminal

```
sudo apt purge nodejs npm
```

then install nvm and use it

[Video Explanation](https://youtu.be/OT7QOFvs9Lk)

to [download and install nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm):

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash
```

to download and install the latest version of node:

```
nvm install node
```

To update node later on, just do:

```
nvm install node
nvm alias default node
```

Comment: This should be the only accepted answer - in case you want to have a sane and up to date Node setup in Ubuntu.

Comment: This also works the best for me (have pretty ancient nodejs on our EC2 and tried lots of suggestions and only this one made it work). Also 100% agree with the comment above!

Comment: `nvm` installs Node.js on a per-user basis. Using `nvm` will not give you a system-wide `node` command. So I would advice against removing the global/system `node` so scripts running as another user can still run `node`.

Comment: @d4nyll good remark, but it is mostly applied to multiuser systems.

Comment: While nvm can be pretty handy, be cautious that it increases bash startup time dramatically.

Comment: Thanks worked to me

Comment: It is better to use `nvm install --lts` to get the **long-term support** version. `nvm install node` willl install the latest **Current** version.
`

Comment: `npm i node`. Let each program specify in its deps what version of `node` it wants to use. Don't depend on the system node.

Answer (score 27):

**Note**: This PPA is out of date and not maintained anymore; you should consider other answers instead of this one.

You can install the latest version from PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: I think this would be a better answer if you (also) provided a non-ppa way of doing this, ppas are notoriously known for becoming outdated and unmaintained, essentially making the answer useless.

Comment: @bigbadonk420 yeah, if you just googled it, probably better to skip the first line  and do just update and install-worked for me with node 0.10.34

Comment: @Capaj nope. that didn't help...

Comment: Don't recommend using this ppa any more, it seems to be rather out of date.

Answer (score 27):

I use NVM to handle my Node versions. Very simple to set up and easy to use.

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh | bash
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

To install NVM globally instead, use the following curl command instead of the one above (and presumably don't use the second command but do use the third one)

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh | NVM_DIR=/usr/local/nvm bash
```

Then use `nvm install stable` (or insert a version number instead of `stable`) to get the latest/a specific version of Node. Use `nvm use stable` (or a specific version number) to use that Node version. Use `nvm ls` to see what Node versions you have installed and `nvm uninstall stable`(or a specific version number) to remove a specific version of Node.

Sources:
[Install](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.markdown#install-script), [usage](https://davidwalsh.name/nvm)

##### Note

If you are struggling with updating `npm` to the latest stable version because you are stuck at a specific version of `npm` and every time you update it that doesn't work then you can use this method to update `npm` as well. As soon as you install the latest stable version of `node`, `npm` will automatically be updated to its latest stable version.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Apologies for my noobness. Updated answer

Comment: the given curl path is not working. I used "curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.13.1/install.sh | bash" as given in the https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: Don't forget to update the url part to the latest version of nvm

Answer (score 14):

#### NVM (Node Version manager) with `--lts`

NVM was mentioned at: https://askubuntu.com/a/441527/52975 but here goes a more complete usage example, including the sane `--lts` version, which installs the latest Long Term Support version of Node, which is likely the one you want if you don't have more specific requirement.

Install NVM and the latest Node LTS version:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install --lts
nvm use --lts
npm --version
```

Now test it out with a dummy package:

```
npm install --global vaca
vaca
```

Since the sourcing has to be done for every new shell, the install script hacks adds some auto sourcing to the end of your `.barshrc`. That works, but I prefer to remove the auto-added one and add my own:

```
f="$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh"
if [ -r "$f" ]; then
  . "$f" &>'/dev/null'
  nvm use --lts &>'/dev/null'
fi
```

Advantages:

- allows you to use multiple versions of Node and without sudo
- is analogous to Ruby RVM and Python Virtualenv, widely considered best practice in Ruby and Python communities
- downloads a pre-compiled binary where possible, and if not it downloads the source and compiles one for you

We can easily switch node versions with:

```
nvm install 0.9.0
nvm install 0.9.9
nvm use 0.9.0
node --version
#v0.9.0
nvm use 0.9.9
node --version
#v0.9.9
```

You can then use a git tracked `.nvmrc` file to indicate the node version required for a given project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869959/how-do-i-specify-a-local-version-of-node-for-a-project/54503474#54503474

With this setup, you get for example:

```
which node
```

gives:

```
/home/ciro/.nvm/versions/node/v0.9.0/bin/node
```

and:

```
which vaca
```

gives:

```
/home/ciro/.nvm/versions/node/v0.9.0/bin/vaca
```

and if we want to use the globally installed module:

```
npm link vaca
node -e 'console.log(require.resolve("vaca"))'
```

gives:

```
/home/ciro/.nvm/versions/node/v0.9.0/lib/node_modules/vaca/index.js
```

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636367/nodejs-require-a-global-module-package
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970793/how-do-i-import-global-modules-in-node-i-get-error-cannot-find-module-module

so we see that everything is completely contained inside the specific node version.

Tested in Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: its worked for me

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me

Answer (score 6):

#### CLEAN SIMPLE STEPS (which I use) :

1. Uninstall previous version of node -
   `sudo apt remove node && sudo apt autoremove`
2. Go to https://nodejs.org/en/ and download the latest version of
   node.
3. Now open the terminal and change the directory where node is
   downloaded and then run-
   `tar -xvf node-v12.16.2-linux-x64.tar.xz`
4. now run this in terminal -
   `nano ~/.bashrc`
5. and append it with the following –
   `export PATH=/path/to/node-js/bin:$PATH`
   Where,
   **/path/to/node-js/** is to be replaced where you extracted node in step 3.`
6. run a last command `source ~/.bashrc`

That's it.
Now you can check your node version by `node -v`

Answer (score 4):

I tried the same list commands on my ubuntu 14.04 but it was still throwing an error.

Commands I executed were:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

and the error i was getting:

```
Invalid version 0.12.2
Line 299: curl not found in /bin/n
```

What I figured out was curl utility was not installed on my os.

I executed  command:

```
apt-get install curl
```

(use `sudo` as prefix if you are not `su`)

and then repeated the steps suggest in answer and it work ;)

Answer (score 2):

This one installs the latest node v0.12.* from nodesource.

```
sudo apt-get install -y curl
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

For node v4.x

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: Are you installing node from scratch? The question was about updating not installing

Answer (score 2):

If using `n` does not work, you can install the latest version of `nodejs` (i. e. version 8) running the following commands:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Further instructions are [here](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions).

Answer (score 2):

Using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) is preferred method. First install nvm:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash
```

Then install nodejs:

```
nvm install node
```

Now on, you can easy switch versions of node.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to install via `nvm`, as described above, but faced some error in Ubuntu 18.04. Then I went through this process:

```
sudo apt purge nodejs npm

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash

nvm install node
```

After running this command, you might get this error:

```
Command 'nvm' not found, did you mean:
```

In that case you can run this command:

```
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

OR you can put it in the `/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` file to automatically load it.

After that you can run the following commands:

```
nvm install node
nvm alias default node
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you first remove all nodejs installs
then execute the below script once you edit with the desired nodejs version and its install parent directory

see all available nodejs versions

https://nodejs.org/dist/

The below script will allow you to install any of those nodejs versions on linux or OSX

```
#!/bin/bash

#     usage :
#
#     edit two vars in below :  NODE_VER  and  CODE_PARENT_DIR
#
# ... execute this script as yourself unless you choose a root-owned value for var CODE_PARENT_DIR
#     whichever id you execute this as determines the id you will issue npm commands as:  npm install -g foo-bar
#
#     NOTE - nodejs comes bundled with npm ... so no need to do separate npm install
#            This script runs fine on Linux or OSX

# ...  copy all the lines starting here  .. top of copy  ....   and ending ... end of copy  ...
#      and paste into your ~/.bashrc file so proper env vars get set 

# ............... top of copy  ........................  install_node.sh

# export NODE_VER=v7.2.0  # see available versions at https://nodejs.org/dist/
# export NODE_VER=v8.5.0  # edit this line next time you need to update nodejs  
export NODE_VER=v9.3.0  # edit this line next time you need to update nodejs

# ...  pick parent dir of nodejs install  ... comment out or remove ONE of below
# export CODE_PARENT_DIR=/opt/code  # root-owned dir ... requires you to sudo prior to npm install going forward
export CODE_PARENT_DIR=${HOME}    # RECOMMENDED executing as yourself including npm install

# ......... following env vars are OK no edits needed ... only ever need to edit above vars

curr_OS=$( uname )

echo curr_OS $curr_OS

if [[ "${curr_OS}" == "Darwin" ]]; then

    OS_ARCH=darwin-x64

elif [[ "${curr_OS}" == "Linux" ]]; then

    OS_ARCH=linux-x64
else
    echo "ERROR - failed to recognize OS $curr_OS"
    exit 5
fi

if [[ -z ${CODE_PARENT_DIR} ]]; then

    echo "ERROR - failed to see env var CODE_PARENT_DIR"
    exit 5
fi

export NODE_CODEDIR=${CODE_PARENT_DIR}/nodejs
export COMSUFFIX=tar.gz
export NODE_NAME=node-${NODE_VER}
export NODE_PARENT=${NODE_CODEDIR}/${NODE_NAME}-${OS_ARCH} 

export PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/bin:${PATH}
export NODE_PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/lib/node_modules

# ............... end of copy  ........................  install_node.sh

# copy and paste above from ... top of copy ... to here into your file ~/.bashrc   

echo
echo "NODE_CODEDIR $NODE_CODEDIR<--"
echo

echo "mkdir -p ${NODE_CODEDIR}"
echo
      mkdir -p ${NODE_CODEDIR}
echo

echo "cd ${NODE_CODEDIR}"
      cd ${NODE_CODEDIR}
echo

# this is compiled code NOT source

[ -f ${NODE_NAME}-${OS_ARCH}.${COMSUFFIX} ] && rm ${NODE_NAME}-${OS_ARCH}.${COMSUFFIX} # if file exists remove

echo "wget -q --show-progress https://nodejs.org/download/release/${NODE_VER}/${NODE_NAME}-${OS_ARCH}.${COMSUFFIX}"
      wget -q --show-progress https://nodejs.org/download/release/${NODE_VER}/${NODE_NAME}-${OS_ARCH}.${COMSUFFIX}
echo

echo "tar -C ${NODE_CODEDIR} -xf ${NODE_NAME}-${OS_ARCH}.${COMSUFFIX}"
      tar -C ${NODE_CODEDIR} -xf ${NODE_NAME}-${OS_ARCH}.${COMSUFFIX}
echo

[ -f ${NODE_NAME}-${OS_ARCH}.${COMSUFFIX} ] && rm ${NODE_NAME}-${OS_ARCH}.${COMSUFFIX} # if file exists remove

# ...........  done ........... #

which node

node --version

# ....  bottom of file   install_node.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

The selected [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/480642/247771) did not work for me, I tried restarting terminal and PC but no success.

I have installed (as recommended in the docs) npm and node with node version manager. In this case, one can update node and npm simply with

```
nvm install stable
```

I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59575266/2311074) how to switch to reinstall with node-verion-manager if you have installed npm/node with Node installer.

Comment: the only answer that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Type following command:

```
sudo npm install n -g
sudo n stable
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Snap, this does the trick, quick and trouble free in my experience

```
sudo snap install node --classic
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a proxy, maybe you could get this error when you run 'sudo n stable':

```
Error: invalid version
```

You have to set the env variables like this:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://your-proxy-url:port
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://your-proxy-url:port
```

And then run the command passing these variables to the root user:

```
sudo -E n stable
```

Comment: Credits to: https://github.com/tj/n/issues/430

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
nvm install --lts

Installing latest LTS version.
Downloading and installing node v18.16.1...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v18.16.1/node-v18.16.1-linux-x64.tar.xz...
####################################################################### 100,0%
Computing checksum with sha256sum
Checksums matched!
Now using node v18.16.1 (npm v9.5.1)
Creating default alias: default -> lts/* (-> v18.16.1)
```

---

```
nvm alias default PUT_VERSION_HERE

e.g.:

nvm alias default v18.16.1

default -> v18.16.1
```

Confirm:

```
node --version
```

Comment: How did you install nvm or did you use the method in sayalok's answer?

Comment: This is not part of OP's question. It was already installed.

Comment: I know it's not part of the OP's question, but how else can I check your answer?

Answer (score 0):

NVS (Node Version Switcher)

I like NVS because has feature for migrate current version to newer, include bringing globally installed packages to target update version

Install on Linux

```
export NVS_HOME="$HOME/.nvs"
git clone https://github.com/jasongin/nvs "$NVS_HOME"
. "$NVS_HOME/nvs.sh" install
```

More info:

- https://github.com/jasongin/nvs

Answer (score 0):

**NVM (Node Version Manager)**

I found NVM is the simplest way to install and manage multiple versions of Node.js on Ubuntu. The command `nvm list-remote` lists all the available versions. You can install the required version by specifying the version details in a user-friendly way.

nvm install v18.19.1 --> this installs a specific version

nvm install lts/iron  --> This installs the latest LTS in the Iron series

Source: [How To Install Node.js on Ubuntu 22.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-22-04?utm_medium=affiliates&utm_source=impact&utm_campaign=2334778&utm_content=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yieldkit.com%2F&irgwc=1&irclickid=ys4QnRXp1xyPWEQ1on0FowlwUkHUFQ0cZQ6e200)