# How do you update npm to the latest version?

Tags: 14.04, nodejs

I'm having issues with `npm` in a Vagrant box I'm setting up. I noticed that the `npm` version is somewhat old, so I wanted to check the problem with the latest release.

It is my understanding that you should be able to update `npm` using `npm install -g npm`, but the command has no effect on the `npm` being used:

```
vagrant@box:~$ npm -v
1.3.10
vagrant@box:~$ sudo npm install -g npm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-2.1.12.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-2.1.12.tgz
/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@2.1.12 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
vagrant@box:~$ npm -v
1.3.10
```

I also tried using `n` (as suggested in [How can I update my nodeJS to the latest version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version)) to update, but it affects neither `npm` nor `node`:

```
vagrant@box:~$ node -v
v0.10.25
vagrant@box:~$
vagrant@box:~$ sudo npm install -g n
/usr/bin/n -> /usr/lib/node_modules/n/bin/n
n@1.2.9 /usr/lib/node_modules/n
vagrant@box:~$ sudo n stable

     install : v0.10.33
       mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/0.10.33
       fetch : http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.33/node-v0.10.33-linux-x64.tar.gz
   installed : v0.10.33

vagrant@box:~$ node -v
v0.10.25
vagrant@box:~$ npm -v
1.3.10
```

What do I have to do to update npm to the latest version?

Comment: Are you sure there is a newer version available? Because for me, 1.3.10 is the latest version available in official repo.

Comment: @RegisteredUser: In my first output listing it even says `2.1.12`, which is the latest release: https://github.com/npm/npm/releases

Comment: Try, $ sudo npm install npm -g

Comment: @vembutech: I did. Unless you're suggesting that the `-g` should be placed somewhere else on the command line.

Comment: `which npm` is very helpful. Old `npm` was in `/usr/local/bin` and has priority above `/usr/bin` new one

Comment: when you use nvm, this is all a non-issue.  because it is per user and per project, everything just works

Answer (score 164, accepted):

I still don't understand *why*, but I have to run `npm install -g npm` **twice** for it to have the desired effect:

```
vagrant@box:~$ npm -v
1.3.10
vagrant@box:~$ sudo npm install -g npm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-2.1.12.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-2.1.12.tgz
/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@2.1.12 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
vagrant@box:~$ npm -v
1.3.10
vagrant@box:~$ sudo npm install -g npm
/usr/bin/npm -> /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@2.1.12 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm
vagrant@box:~$ npm -v
2.1.12
```

Comment: If you recently reconfigured to stop `sudo`, as suggested here: http://justjs.com/posts/npm-link-developing-your-own-npm-modules-without-tears, you may have altered your ~/.bashrc file. Thus, be sure to run `source ~/.bashrc` or else `npm -v` won't find the updated version.

Comment: I just closed and reopened my shell instance to see the updated version.

Comment: For me it worked from the first time.

Comment: I had to do this twice also in 14.04 before it was picked up. Wouldn't have guessed otherwise. Cheers

Comment: No idea, how I got there, but this might help someone: after you have installed nodejs as explained here `https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/`, you have to restart your terminal and it will be there. You *do not* need to install `npm` separately! 
So you also won't need to install and update `npm`.

Comment: @Ufos  For me, I do need to install npm separately.  What dist are you using?  Thanks

Comment: @user1032531 xubuntu 14.04. I also thought I do have to, and tried to install it separately which only led to `npm` not working at all. Later I realized that after installing node I simply had to restart the terminal. 

For the installation I used 
`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

Comment: The reason for why it does not pick it up straight away is explained in my answer, below. TL;DR Bash caches the path of each command you use, so if you move it, you have to update it's cache.

Comment: sudo npm upgrade  -g npm, i used and also solved my problem

Comment: You should never use sudo with `npm -g`, instead configure your permissions correctly.

Comment: running: npm i -g npm  instead of  npm install -g npm seems to take effect from the first time.

Answer (score 65):

When you first do `npm install -g npm`, the shell (Bash) will search for `npm` in your path, find `/usr/bin/npm` installed by the system package, and then use it to install the new version of `npm`. The new version will be installed in `/usr/local/bin/npm`.

Now, your path should have `/usr/local/bin/` BEFORE `/usr/bin/`, so you would think it would now pick up the updated version in `/usr/local/bin/`, right? Wrong.

Bash will CACHE executable paths after the first time it searches for them, so when you say `npm` the 2nd time, it is still using the cached version which it first found as `/usr/bin/npm`.

To tell Bash to clear this cache and look through the path again, you have to do a `hash -r`.

After installing `npm` and doing this, my shell picked up the new version of `npm` just fine.

Thanks

Comment: this worked for me on 14.04 Thanks! -- http://prnt.sc/bybbao

Comment: This worked for me,Thank you. All other answer did not work.

Comment: Perfect and clear answer it worked for me

Comment: Windows 10 Bash 14.04 this worked for me after updating

Comment: `hash -r` save my ass. XD

Comment: `hash -r` did it for me too!

Comment: This helped me.  Thanks!

Comment: Is this a windows command?  I'm on win 8.1 thx  I updated node to most stable today (12.x) and while I had npm 6.10.x as the npm version _BEFORE_ the newer install on my laptop, after the install, npm 3.8.0 shows as my version

Answer (score 46):

You can update nodejs by using npm itself, a PPA, or manually.

**npm**:

Check the current version you have:

```
node -v
```

The following clears your cache.

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
```

Install `n`

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

You can tell it to install a specific version like so:

```
sudo n 0.8.11
```

Or just tell it to install the latest stable version. Both may take a while.

```
sudo n stable
```

To see if it actually upgraded, run:

```
node -v
```

**PPA**:

Other option is to install it via a [PPA by chris-lea](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/ubuntu/node.js);

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

This PPA Supports the following distros: Utopic (14.10), Trusty (14.04), Saucy (13.10), Raring (13.04), Quantal (12.10), Precise (12.04), Oneiric (11.10), Natty (11.04), Lucid (10.04).

**Manually**:

You can always update it by manually [downloading](http://nodejs.org/download/) the latest version and installing it yourself!

---

**Reference**:

- [Upgrade Node.js via NPM](http://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs)
- [Node.js fundamentals: how to upgrade the Node.js version | The Holmes Office](http://theholmesoffice.com/node-js-fundamentals-how-to-upgrade-the-node-js-version/)
- [node.js : chris lea](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/ubuntu/node.js)
- [node.js - downloads](http://nodejs.org/download/)

Comment: I know you're trying to help, but that is exactly what it says in my question.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg , my bad, i saw the above post, and was to noisy for me to read. So, i just started posting, my own answer.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg, I updated my answer with multiple option on how to upgrade!

Comment: awesome, using n worked well for me (debian sid)

Comment: This is obviously the correct answer. It annoys me when question posters answer the own question 'WRONGLY' then mark it as accepted. They should be penalized!

Comment: This worked for me after having tried a various approaches. I had to start a new session to refresh everything because `node -v` was throwing an error, but on starting a new terminal it worked with the updated version

Comment: This is still an issue somehow, 9 years later. Way harder updating npm than it should be

Answer (score 23):

#### Update NPM to latest version in one command

To upgrade or update the version of your npm, just type in terminal:

```
sudo npm install npm@latest -g
```

As mentioned in the footer of the [NPM documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/)

Comment: I did this but EC Ubuntu is still showing older version of npm, how to fix it ?

Comment: Just relog to your account.

Answer (score 12):

Most of the time I'm unable to upgrade it with the global command. What worked for me however is upgrading the package from the source of all the systems node-modules:

**Find out where npm is installed and go into that folder**

```
# Below command shows the destination (remove sed pipe to see the full path of npm-cli)
whereis npm | cut -c 6- | xargs readlink -f | sed 's/.\{19\}$//'

# Go in there and install it manually. In my case it was the folder below... 
# NOTE: on mac its in /usr/local/lib
cd /usr/lib
sudo npm install npm@latest
```

**Behold the mighty one-liner for everybody (especially lazy people)**

```
cd `whereis npm | cut -c 6- | xargs readlink -f | sed 's/.\{18\}$//'`; cd ..; sudo npm install npm@latest
```

Comment: This runs free of error for me (in contrast to other answers) however npm remains not updated

Comment: if you `sudo` it uses the npm folder of the root account, be aware of that. If you want to know where your npm is, simply type: `whereis npm | xargs readlink -f`. Maybe you just upgraded the wrong package there. I've added some info to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Any trick you do, don't use `Git`, I recommand running them in the `Composer terminal`. It'll surely work. It did for me by `npm install npm -g`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to reinstall something that is ready there, just use **update -g** built into the package manager to update itself:

```
$ npm -v
2.15.1
$ sudo npm update -g npm
/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@3.10.9 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
$ npm -v
3.10.9
```

Make sure that global flag **-g** is before the packages.  I've had problems in the past with npm not registering the flag after the package list.

Comment: I had to restart the terminal for the change to reflect

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade `npm` you need to update `nodejs` to the latest version which includes `npm`

In debian stretch and jessie use this script :

```
#install prerequisites
apt-get install apt-transport-https curl git lsb-release -y

#Install NodeJS from external repositories
DISTRO=$(lsb_release -c -s)
if [ "$DISTRO" == "stretch" ]
then
  DISTRO="jessie"
fi

if curl -f "https://deb.nodesource.com/node_7.x/dists/$DISTRO/Release" >/dev/null
then
  curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add -
  echo "deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_7.x $DISTRO main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
  echo "deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_7.x $DISTRO main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
  apt-get update
  # comment out the following line, if you installed nodejs 7 already (check with `apt-cache policy nodejs`)
  apt-get remove nodejs nodejs-legacy npm
  apt-get install nodejs -y
else
  echo -e "Your distribution is not supported by NodeJS. \nYou have to install a recent NodeJS version (>=4) manually. "
fi
```

In Ubuntu, you can use this script from https://deb.nodesource.com:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

see the source first at https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/deb/setup_7.x

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to nodejs v0.12.7

```sh
# Note the new setup script name for Node.js v0.12
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -

# Then install with:
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Source: [Node.js v0.12, io.js, and the NodeSource Linux Repositories | nodesource.com](https://nodesource.com/blog/nodejs-v012-iojs-and-the-nodesource-linux-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the problem. My current npm version was `3.3.12` but I tried `sudo npm install npm -g`, `sudo npm update npm -g` .. nothing worked.. while I `npm --version` I always get `3.3.12`. I searched for directories in my Ubuntu 15.04 and found two version of npm in different directory.

- v3.3.12 in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm`
- v3.6 in `/usr/lib/node_modules/npm`

So I did make a copy of 3.3.12 with `mv npm npm_3312` while I was in older npm directory. Then I did `sudo cp -r npm /usr/local/lib/node_modules/` while I was in '/usr/lib/node_modules' directory.. I made my `npm --version` and I got `3.6.0`

:D