# Should I run `npm install -g npm` if my current npm was installed with apt?

Tags: apt, updates, nodejs, npm

Whenever I use `npm`, I get a big fat warning:

```
╭────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                                │
│      New major version of npm available! 6.14.11 → 7.12.1      │
│   Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.12.1   │
│               Run npm install -g npm to update!                │
│                                                                │
╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

The current `npm` version is the one that came with my distibution (Kubuntu 20.10, will be updating to 21.04 soon).

Is it safe/advised to let `npm` update itself without using the apt package manager?

I have managed to (temporarily) destroy my nodejs/npm installs more than once in the past, so I'd rather be safe than sorry.

Comment: [This answer from a few years back](https://askubuntu.com/a/562435/1222991) will give you what you need if you choose to update 

Comment: @matigo Thank you, but the linked answer does not explain what `npm install -g npm` does when npm is installed as an apt package.  For example, what will happen if I (or a distro update) updates the npm package? Which update "wins"? Will there be inconsistencies with other packages provided by the distribution?