# I'm not able to upgrade NodeJS on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, wget, nodejs

I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and I installed NodeJS 0.10. I am now trying to upgrade to version 5 of NodeJS.

I used the commands below to upgrade:

```
wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install --yes nodejs
```

Comment: What was the output of those commands? How did you install NodeJS in the first place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I update my nodeJS to the latest version?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version)

Comment: I see that you still haven't accepted my answer. I it helped you, which I hope I did, please accept my answer by following the instructions here http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n)? With `n` you can interactively manage all your Node versions. You can have any amount of versions, for example 0.10.44 and 5.10.1 *alongside* each other.

How to do it:

1. Install `npm` with `sudo apt-get install npm`.
2. `sudo npm install n -g`.
3. `sudo n stable` or any of the results of `n ls` to download and install that `node` version.
4. Sit back and let it install.
5. To verify that the installation was successful, type `node -v`.

To install another `node` version, simply run `sudo n <version>` (e.g `0.10`). To switch, type `sudo n` and select your preferred version with the arrow up and down keys.