# Node Bash path confusion on Ubuntu 16 using n

Tags: bash, nodejs

I tried to install n for node version updates following [this answers direction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version). It was successful in upgrading me to node v7 but had a side effect. Node is now found:

```
/usr/local/bin/node
```

If I type `node -v` I get a bash error because it's looking in the wrong place (it looks in `usr/bin/node`). What is my best path forward? How do I change the path where my terminal looks for node so I can run `node index.js` while not interfering with my desire to use n to upgrade node in the future.

**I'm not sure if this is relevant** but, when I'm in a project and I type `nodemon index.js` everything works as expected. I think that this is due to the fact that nodemon is installed where node v7 is installed.

Here is the value of `echo $PATH`:

```
    /usr/local/heroku/bin:/home/devin/.rbenv/shims:/home/devin/.rbenv/bin:/usr/bin:/home/devin/bin:/home/devin/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Here is the value of `which node`:

```
/usr/local/bin/node
```

The value of `locate node` overloads the terminal and ends like this:

```
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.1.2/lib/arel/nodes/node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.1.2/lib/arel/nodes/outer_join.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.1.2/lib/arel/nodes/over.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.1.2/lib/arel/nodes/regexp.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.1.2/lib/arel/nodes/right_outer_join.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.1.2/lib/arel/nodes/select_core.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.1.2/lib/arel/nodes/select_statement.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.1.2/lib/arel/nodes/sql_literal.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.1.2/lib/arel/nodes/string_join.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.1.2/lib/arel/nodes/table_alias.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.1.2/lib/arel/nodes/terminal.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.1.2/lib/arel/nodes/true.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.1.2/lib/arel/nodes/unary.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.1.2/lib/arel/nodes/unary_operation.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.1.2/lib/arel/nodes/unqualified_column.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.1.2/lib/arel/nodes/update_statement.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.1.2/lib/arel/nodes/values.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.1.2/lib/arel/nodes/window.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.1.2/lib/arel/nodes/with.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/support/node_runner.js
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri/xml_node.c
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri/xml_node.h
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri/xml_node.o
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri/xml_node_set.c
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri/xml_node_set.h
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri/xml_node_set.o
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri/css/node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri/xml/node
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri/xml/node/save_options.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri/xml/pp/node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/test/html/test_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/test/html/test_node_encoding.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/test/xml/node
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/test/xml/test_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/test/xml/test_node_attributes.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/test/xml/test_node_encoding.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/test/xml/test_node_inheritance.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/test/xml/test_node_reparenting.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/test/xml/test_node_set.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/test/xml/test_unparented_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/test/xml/node/test_save_options.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/test/xml/node/test_subclass.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/at_root_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/charset_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/comment_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/content_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/css_import_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/debug_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/directive_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/each_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/error_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/extend_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/for_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/function_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/if_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/keyframe_rule_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/media_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/mixin_def_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/mixin_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/prop_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/return_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/rule_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/supports_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/trace_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/variable_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/warn_node.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/while_node.rb
```

Comment: What's the output of `echo $PATH` and `which node` and `locate node` Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek I've updated the question with the answer to your request. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for that. I'd still like to see the output of the other 2 commands as well.

Comment: @ElderGeek Thanks much for your questions. I believe those questions helped the other user answer the question. I selected his answer as correct. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help. That was my intent and I'm glad it worked out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You need to add another PATH to your environment variables.**

In case this is the first time you've had to do this, I'll try to explain the logic behind what to do.

Whenever you run a command, your terminal shell will try to run the first word. Your shell has a PATH environment variable list where it will check for the command you run (e.g. `node`) by going through the list of paths it knows until it finds it. You can check what your PATH is by typing in the Terminal:

```
echo $PATH
```

The file's path (i.e. `/usr/local/bin/` of `/usr/local/bin/node`) is likely not on the list. The different paths are separated by colons, showing something like this:

```
/home/user/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

**Appending the file's path (`/usr/local/bin/`) to your shell's PATH in its rc file should be enough.** A shell rc file is a 'runcom' file which literally means 'run commands' when the shell instance starts. In bash, it's located at `~/.bashrc`. If you use something else, you'll need to look up what it is, like for zsh it's `~/.zshrc`.

Open the file and on the line that looks something like `export PATH="...$PATH"` and add a `:/usr/local/bin/` to the end of it.

It may look something like this:

```
export PATH="[other paths]:$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
```

If you don't have a line like that anywhere in the file, just add a new line with this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
```

Save the rc file and close and re-open your terminal and you'll be able to use node as a command. You should also be able to see the new path added when running `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Thanks very much for this clear answer. I've messed around with paths a few times but never with a high level of confidence. This answer clearly solved my issue and I feel equipped to handle similar issues in the future.