# Error message updating node.js

Tags: apt, nodejs

this is my first question on the community and I am quiet a newbie to Ubuntu. I am on version 16.04.

I am trying to update my node.js following the steps on the best answer in this post:

[How can I update my nodeJS to the latest version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version)

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable

sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/<VERSION>/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```

At first everything went out ok, but when I typed the last line, I got this error in the Terminal:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/7.8.0/bin/node/ usr/bin/node
ln: fallo al crear el enlace simbólico 'usr/bin/node': No existe el 
archivo o el directorio
```

That translates (from Google): Failed to create symbolic link 'usr / bin / node': There is no File or directory.

(I guessed that in ../VERSION I had to put 7.8.0, the one in the /node folder, since with VERSION didn't work either and gave me the same error).

Appreciate the help!

Comment: just make the same name directory over there nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Make a directory with name node over there. Means move to directory path usr/bin/ and make (mkdir node) directory with name node over there. It will resolve you problem.