# NPM is incorrect version on latest Ubuntu (18.04) installation

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, nodejs, npm

Normal installation would be `sudo apt install nodejs` to install Node.js and then `sudo apt install npm` to install Node Package Manager. However, upon doing so, `npm -v` says `3.5.2`. To upgrade normally, I would do `sudo npm install -g npm`, which updates to the latest version (which, at the time of writing this article, is `6.0.1`).

When I do a `which npm`, I get `/usr/local/bin/npm`, however `apt` installs a symlink at `/usr/bin/npm`. If I `sudo apt purge npm` to remove npm, it still leaves the npm version of npm at `/usr/local/bin/npm`, however `npm -v` says `-bash: /usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory`.

Many articles say to use a PPA to install nodejs, but I think there should be a native way to do this through `apt`.

**DigitalOcean instructions on installation normally and through PPA:** https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-18-04

**TecAdmin instructions on installation through PPA:** https://tecadmin.net/install-latest-nodejs-npm-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**TLDR:** This problem is caused by [Bash caching the path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables) of the `npm` command, and can be solved by **`hash -d npm`**.  You don't even need to deal with `apt purge` unless you want to.

### Explanation

Here were my steps for getting a new `npm` version on Ubuntu.  First, do the installation as OP describes:

```
$ sudo apt-get install npm
(...apt installation of npm was successful...)
$ npm -v
3.5.2
$ command -v npm
/usr/bin/npm
$ sudo npm install -g npm
(...npm installation of npm was successful...so far, so good)
```

You can see that the new version is already working fine in `/usr/local/bin/npm`, but unfortunately the Bash cache still has `/usr/bin/npm`:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/npm -v
6.4.1
$ npm -v
3.5.2
$ command -v npm
/usr/bin/npm
$ type npm
npm is hashed (/usr/bin/npm)
```

To fix the problem, clear it from the Bash cache (do this in all open shells):

```
$ hash -d npm
```

Now the new version works as desired:

```
$ npm -v
6.4.1
$ command -v npm
/usr/local/bin/npm
```

Comment: I actually like this answer better than my own.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you so much. Great explanation, too. The one thing that's unclear to me is the exact nature of why clearing the bash cache fixes the problem. Wouldn't it be better to delete the `npm` stored at `/usr/bin/npm`? And why is the right version picked up after clearing the bash cache, if both versions remain installed?

Comment: @temporary_user_name You can see the path using `echo $PATH`, which shows that `/usr/local/bin` will be preferred before `/usr/bin` if both targets exist when Bash looks through the path. Bash looks through the path only if it doesn't remember where it found the target before.

Comment: Lifesaver! Thx. I was stuck trying to do a production build for hours. This solved the issue.

Comment: All I had to do was `hash -d npm` then everything was running!!! Thanks alot!!!

Answer (score 12):

The way I found is to purge npm through `sudo apt purge npm`, then simply recreate a symlink to the global installation via `ln -s /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm`. After that fix, `npm -v` returns `6.0.1` as expected.

Comment: Worked with Ubuntu 18.04 running through [UserLAnd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tech.ula) on Android 6.0.1. Thank you! :)

Comment: OP you should mark this as the answer.

Comment: Weird thing, for me it was quite different. I had the updated version in `/usr/bin/npm`, so I went the opposite route using `ln -s /usr/bin/npm /usr/local/bin/npm`. Strange, but your answer helped me to find out how to deal with the incorrect version issue.

Answer (score 2):

To have control on installed npm version, I always use `nvm` (node version control). You can install it through the instructions here: https://github.com/creationix/nvm
Then by following command install the latest npm on your computer:

`nvm install node`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately none of the other answers worked for me. Here is how I got it to work on Ubuntu 18.04.

**tl;dr** do this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v10.16.3-linux-x64/bin/npm /usr/local/bin
```

### **Explanation:**

I had installed npm via the default repositories (i.e. not PPA) which installed the `npm` executable to `/usr/bin/npm`.

When I updated it with `sudo npm install -g npm`, a new executable was installed to `/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v10.16.3-linux-x64/bin/npm`.

To get `npm` to work for a non-root user, you can put the following in that user's `~/.profile` file (which I think is what is done when doing `npm install -g npm` without `sudo`):

```
# Nodejs
VERSION=v10.16.3
DISTRO=linux-x64
export PATH=/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-$VERSION-$DISTRO/bin:$PATH
```

However since this directory is not in root's `$PATH` environment variable it won't work for `sudo` commands:

```
$ sudo npm -v
3.5.2
```

As you can see, `sudo` does not use the latest npm, but instead uses the one installed via the package manager.

The root's default `$PATH` on Ubuntu is:

```
root ~# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```

Since the package manager version of npm was installed in `/usr/bin`, we can just create a symbolic link to put the latest version higher up the `$PATH` priority chain, like `/usr/local/bin`, and this way it also won't be overwritten if the package manager version is ever updated:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v10.16.3-linux-x64/bin/npm /usr/local/bin
$ sudo npm -v                                                                                                                                                                                                    
6.14.1
```

**Note** I'm assuming that if node is ever updated as well, this path will change, so you will have to repeat this step with the updated path:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v10.16.3-linux-x64/bin/npm
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/nodejs/{NEW_NODE_VERSION}-linux-x64/bin/npm /usr/local/bin
```