# How can I install forever-monitor on ubuntu

Tags: npm

Where do I make a mistake?.. I can't install it under the ubuntu

I have two devices: jetson nano and desktop ubuntu 18

I am running the following command:

```
$npm i -g forever-monitor
```

I get the same error when I try to install forever-monitor on both
devices

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.9.140-tegra 
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "i" "forever-monitor" 
npm ERR! node v8.10.0 
npm ERR! npm v3.5.2 
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG
npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1 
npm ERR! typeerror at andLogAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3) 
npm ERR! typeerror at fetchPackageMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22) 
npm ERR! typeerror at resolveWithNewModule (/usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:456:12) 
npm ERR! typeerror at /usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:7 
npm ERR! typeerror at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50 
npm ERR! typeerror at /usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12 
npm ERR! typeerror at addRequestedAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:82:5) 
npm ERR! typeerror at returnAndAddMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:117:7) 
npm ERR! typeerror at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:134:20) 
npm ERR! typeerror at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50 
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at: 
npm ERR! typeerror http://github.com/npm/npm/issues 
npm ERR! Linux 4.9.140-tegra 
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "i" "forever-monitor" 
npm ERR! node v8.10.0 
npm ERR! npm v3.5.2 
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG 
npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1 
npm ERR! typeerror at andLogAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3) 
npm ERR! typeerror at fetchPackageMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22) 
npm ERR! typeerror at resolveWithNewModule (/usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:456:12) 
npm ERR! typeerror at /usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:7 
npm ERR! typeerror at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50 
npm ERR! typeerror at /usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12 
npm ERR! typeerror at addRequestedAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:82:5) 
npm ERR! typeerror at returnAndAddMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:117:7) 
npm ERR! typeerror at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:134:20) 
npm ERR! typeerror at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50 
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at: 
npm ERR! typeerror http://github.com/npm/npm/issues 
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /home/bmg/bmg/bmg_deepstream/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Show error from ubuntu, not from `Linux 4.9.140-tegra` jetson nano. And also, specify your ubuntu version: 18.04 or 18.10. 18.10 is not supported as an EOL.

Answer (score 1):

- Check your `npm` version. If you get the next:

  ```
  $ npm -v
  3.5.2
  ```

  Then upgrade your npm:

  ```
  $ sudo npm install -g npm
  ```
- Clear bash cache, so bash will use npm from `/usr/local/bin/` folder:

  ```
  $ hash -d npm
  ```
- `sudo npm -i -g forever-monitor`

**Result:**

```
    + forever-monitor@2.0.0
    added 204 packages from 136 contributors in 10.082s
```

[Reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/1098249/925971)