# Disadvantages of using npm n for upgrading nodejs

Tags: apt, nodejs, npm

### My question

There are [some](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version/480642#comment815042_480642) [criticisms](https://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs) against `npm n`, but they are dated (mostly from < 2018). Do the criticisms still stand? Is `n` unstable or does it have pitfalls? It bears saying that there were 115,014 downloads for `n` this week.

### The problem

I want to install the latest stable versions of npm **and** nodeJS on Ubuntu 20.04, but that's surprisingly difficult.

---

Related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41666010/n-or-nvm-for-managing-node-versions-is-keeping-global-modules-for-each-version
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23569481/4621141
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41196107/4621141
- https://askubuntu.com/a/663050/808646
- https://askubuntu.com/a/1098249/808646

Comment: May I flip the question? What do they say against NVM? Is there less confusion around NVM? Does it do the job reliably?

Comment: @Levente these are good questions too, but the reason I'm also choosing `n` are: 1) it's a module of npm, not a bash script etc.; 2) it's actually very easy to use; 3) from what I saw in regard to nvm, setup seems a bit less convoluted. But I'm facing a problem: active node version points to  `/usr/bin/node`, but I want it to point to my custom folder, where node v14 is installed `~/.n/bin/node`. Lost some hours but I still don't know what to do here. I tried using `n` and selecting v14 (pressing Enter "to install"), but the active version isn't updated (i.e., v14 isn't installed?)

Comment: Solved my problem. I still had node installed (npm must have installed it). Because my changes to `PATH` were appended to the end of it, running `node` would always get me the old version 10 of node. I've updated my question to include all the steps to install it via npm n

Comment: It seems you are providing an answer to your question in your post? Then please move that info to a proper Answer, with the button on the bottom: "Answer your question" (which is a welcome thing to do on AskUbuntu).

Comment: @Levente I think by now the question might have answered itself, I've never run into any problems using `n`. But the original question was whether there could be disadvantages. I'll move the steps into an answer, saying I never had issues, to make the question cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some years running this just fine, I think I can confidently say there are no real issues (at least, I didn't run into them). The only issue is getting `n` to work. For that, read below.

### Solving it with npm n

I'm installing it as a user with sudo access and I don't ever want to `sudo` npm or node to make it work [(why?)](https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92).

1. Install npm: `sudo apt install npm`.
2. [Set prefix for npm](https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92) :  `npm config set prefix ~/.npm`
3. Upgrade npm to the latest version, `npm i -g npm`.

(**Update:** apt's npm is now so old that you should get an error message when trying to update, because the bundled node version is too old. In this case, run this command again at the end of all these instructions)

4. Set environmental variables in `~/.profile` file (these changes will only work after you log out and log in again, or if you run `source ~/.profile`):

```
# vars to avoid ever using sudo for npm
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.npm/bin"
# these are for n and where it'll install nodejs:
export N_PREFIX=$HOME/.n
export PATH="$PATH:$N_PREFIX/bin"
```

You might also want to add these lines to `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` or `~/.bashrc` in case you need to `source ~/.profile` every time you open a new terminal for npm, node and n to be recognized. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18050309) for the reason.

5. Run `source ~/.profile` to update the environmental variables. This way bash will find the path to `npm` and `n` during this session (i.e., without having to log out and then log in again).
6. Use npm `n` package to upgrade node (see: https://askubuntu.com/a/663052/808646):

```
# Intructions: https://www.npmjs.com/package/n
# Some people also suggest npm cache clean -f, but (I think) this isn't necessary here. 
# I'm using lts for the stable release, for the latest use instead: n latest 

npm install -g n
n lts
```

7. Uninstall the previous nodejs that came installed by npm: `sudo apt-get purge nodejs` .

**Explanation**: this step is crucial. So far, this is what happened: you installed `npm`, but it actually installed old `nodejs` and old `npm` on top of it. Although you purportedly "installed" a new `nodejs` using `n`, the previous `nodejs` takes precedence and `n` can't really install the new `nodejs` it downloaded, you must first remove the old one.
However, if you remove it without installing a new `npm`, you will not have `npm` anymore, because uninstalling old `nodejs` uninstalls old `npm` too <sup>(I think... or can it work if you just export all vars again? Maybe just having `n` installed with a nodejs/npm version will be enough?)</sup>. Therefore, you must install a new `npm` (you did that in step 3) and a new `nodejs` using `n` (you did that in step 6) *before* uninstalling old `nodejs`. The reason why you also need a new `nodejs` install is that without a new `nodejs`, new `npm` won't run, it requires a current `nodejs` install.

8. Check if it worked. If it didn't, try logging out and logging in again or enter `n` and select the correct nodejs version (*by default, it'll use the npm that's bundled with that nodejs version, but there are options to prevent this): `node -v`

Answer (score 0):

Running `sudo apt install npm` works fine, but `sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs` will also remove `npm`, putting you back where you started. So I don't see any way around using a non-apt approach for installing the latest version of `nodejs`.

Comment: Hello. This answer does not seem to have anything to do with the question as asked.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your comment (I see you posted this as an answer instead of comment, I hope some mod can delete it). You're right, I think they changed something and now npm is completely intertwined with nodejs, so if you purge the latter you purge the former. I'll rewrite my instructions to fix this

Comment: @BobKline I just updated the steps, if you follow them now they should work. Mods, please delete this answer

Comment: I would have preferred to post a comment, which would have been a more logical thing to do, but the forum blocked me from doing so, saying that I didn't have enough "points" for commenting but I did have enough points to post an "answer." Apparently I am allowed to post comments on my own answers. I'm not sure how these restrictions make sense, but it's not my system. Perhaps it would have been more helpful if those who are offended by the fact that I posted an answer could explain how else I would have been able to convey the problem I saw in the instructions. Thanks for fixing them.

Comment: I suppose it's also possible that by posting my comment as an "answer" I was pushed over the threshold enabling me to post real comments. If so, I will presumably lose that ability when the answer is deleted. 

Comment: I believe you can always comment in the context of your own posts (in case of questions, on the entire page, in case of answers, just under your own answer), but not elsewhere. This works like this until you have accumulated some reputation with normal questions and answers. So removing this post will not affect you negatively. You just really need to work up your rep points a bit with some rewardable question / answer contributions. See https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges

Comment: So you're saying that there's no acceptable way, given my current user status, to provide information I have about a post? Why is that a good thing?

Comment: @BobKline you're correct... and it does suck. On the other hand, I've seen people doing what you did (post a comment as an answer, because they don't have the 'comment' privilege) and then a mod removing their posts afterwards. It's a compromise, if anyone could always comment there'd be many bots posting comments