# No way to upgrade nodejs in this case

Tags: 16.04, nodejs

No matter how I try I end up with nodejs 4.2.6. Is it a joke?

```
$ nodejs -v
v4.2.6
```

Uninstall and 4.2.6 returns like a virus

```
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gyp libjs-inherits libjs-node-uuid libjs-underscore libuv1-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nodejs
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 73 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3 161 kB of archives.
After this operation, 13,2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
(Reading database ... 434000 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_4.2.6~dfsg-1ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (4.2.6~dfsg-1ubuntu4.1) ...
Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.7) ...
Processing 1 added doc-base file...
Registering documents with scrollkeeper...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up nodejs (4.2.6~dfsg-1ubuntu4.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/nodejs to provide /usr/bin/js (js) in auto mode
```

Comment: You install nodejs 4.2.6 and you get nodejs 4.2.6. Not sure what's the problem. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: If you are unhappy with the version of nodejs that Ubuntu 16.04 provides you will find a way to upgrade it here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because Ubuntu provides this version of node js by default. When I installed I got a similar version.

Then I followed [this guide](https://tecadmin.net/install-latest-nodejs-npm-on-ubuntu/). I able to install latest versions. The best way is to download the binary from [the official node site](https://nodejs.org/en/). Then extract the package and add it to a system path location.