# Simplest way to upgrade NodeJs and NPM

Tags: upgrade, nodejs, npm

In nowadays (~2020) not make sense to copy/paste big scripts from internet to install the **official stable version** of a package...

There are a **simpler** (and reliable) way (comparing with [this ugly setpup](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-18-04)) to do it for `node` and `npm`?

---

Notes: I am using fresh Ubuntu 18 LTS and need standard LTS packages, but `apt install`  build very very old versions:

- `node --version` = v8.10.0, but "all people" need v12+ as the official recommendation.
- `npm -v` = 3.5.2, but "all people" need v6+ as the official recommendation.
- I try `sudo snap refresh node --channel=13` but "snap 'node' is not installed"
- [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/480642/439867) seems the only good solution

Comment: Hi @user535733, I tested `apt` and `Snaps` .... Perhaps do something wrong with Snaps

Comment: Check out the [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).
I think the best way to manage your node version.