# how to fix unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

04
I tried to install obs-studio but it doesnt work I updated node before this which also didnt work I think that is what causes the error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs : Depends: libnode72 (= 12.22.5~dfsg-5ubuntu1) but 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
          Recommends: nodejs-doc
 obs-studio : Depends: libavdevice58 (>= 7:4.4) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libluajit-5.1-2 (>= 2.0.4+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmbedcrypto7 (>= 2.28.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmbedtls14 (>= 2.28.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmbedx509-1 (>= 2.28.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libobs0 (= 27.2.3+dfsg1-1) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: obs-plugins (= 27.2.3+dfsg1-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

then i tried `apt --fix-broken install` but then it shows me this error

```
error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_18.12.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp', which is also in package libnode72:amd64 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_18.12.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

i saw a solution on the web that said to use aptitude but i cant even seem to install aptitude . Sorry if this is a very simple error I am beginner but i cant seem to fix it even after trying out all the solutions from the web .
Edit : Sorry i forgot to mention that i am using lubuntu 22.04

Comment: Tell us what OS you are using and what version please. Some reading here https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: @darth_epoxy Amry's using Lubuntu 22.04 and it's written in the question.

Comment: It looks like there's something else wrong with your package management. A PPA in your software sources is causing the unmet dependencies error maybe.